# Tips on finessing Reduce[] with inequalities

Tags: inequalities

Reduce[] sometimes solves inequalities I give it, sometimes it doesn't.  Is there some general principles I'm missing or some common pitfalls I'm falling into?

For example, here is easy problem I can't seem to make MMa solve.

```
Reduce[{4*Abs[p + p^2] < 1, c == 1 - p - p^2}, p]
```

The hand-derived solution is just $|c-1|<\frac{1}{4}$ but MMa gets stuck.

Any pointers?

Comment: Sometimes it depends on the domain. If you add the option `Reals`, i.e. `Reduce[{4*Abs[p + p^2] < 1, c == 1 - p - p^2}, p, Reals]`, it spits back an answer practically instantaneously. It is likely more difficult to solve that problem in the complex plane, which is what it assumes and probably why it gets stuck.

Comment: Or `Reduce[{4*Abs[p + p^2] < 1, c == 1 - p - p^2, {c, p} \[Element] Reals}, {c}, {p}]`...